# Adding pull secrets to service accounts in OpenShift automatically

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, docker-registry

In our project we use Openshift with an external image registry. (Artifactory)

To make that work I need to make sure that every service account contains the corresponding pull secret.

Especially when operators (like strimzi) create service accounts on their own, that's tricky.

Openshift already automatically adds secrets to any new service account. (e.g. to access the internal registry.)

**Is it possible to tell Openshift to also add the credentials for Artifactory automatically?**

Looks like the UI offers a way to configure a "Default Pull Secret" which seems to fit exactly that situation. - Unfortunately I don't see any effect in setting that. - What exactly should it do?
[image: configuration in UI]

Looks like the code for that is [here](https://github.com/openshift/console/blob/master/frontend/public/components/namespace.jsx#L977). (But I don't know jsx well enough to understand what exactly it is doing.)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to solve this in OpenShift, each on a different level:

- Cluster-level
- Project (namespace) level
- Different for each project

Most of these will need to be configured by your OpenShift administrator.

First possibility is to define a **global cluster pull secret** which is [described in the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html#images-update-global-pull-secret_using-image-pull-secrets) and will be applied to all namespaces / projects:

```
$ oc set data secret/pull-secret -n openshift-config --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<pull-secret-location>
```

As an alternative, you can also **add a default pull secret to each new project** by using the "new project template" feature: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/applications/projects/configuring-project-creation.html#modifying-template-for-new-projects_configuring-project-creation

> As a cluster administrator, you can modify the default project template so that new projects are created using your custom requirements.

So your OpenShift Administrator needs to edit the new project template add a `Secret` and `ServiceAccount` that is automatically created for each new project:

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: my-default-secret
  data:
    .dockercfg: <Output of "cat .dockercfg | base64">
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    name: my-serviceaccount
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: my-default-secret
```

If you require **different pull secrets per project** then you'll need to do it via some other functionality (templates, kustomize, ...).

Comment: Could you give a little bit more detail? It looks like in Openshift the "project" object is exactly the same as the namespace object. - Which object needs to be modified to add the pull secrets? (Simply creating the secret is not enough, it needs to be linked whenever a new SA is created.) Especially which object holds the above "Default pull secret"?

Comment: @michas I added some more information and more links to the documentation. Yes, there is a 1-to-1 relationship from a project to a namespace. For the new project template, this is an object that your OpenShift administrator needs to edit (the documentation tells you which one). Automatically adding the secret to a new ServiceAccount will be hard I guess, in that case you'll need to use a **global cluster pull secret**.

Comment: Thanks for the details! "global cluster pull secret" sound basically fine. Unfortunately the cluster team insists on using a dedicated artifactory user **per project**. - Only creating a *single* SA with the secret is no option. I want to make sure that *every* pod in the project uses the secret for that project. (I was hoping that the "Default pull Secret" would do the trick, but I couldn't find any documentation on that one.)

Comment: With a different default pull secret per project you'll likely need to automate this somehow during project creation. Often, people [disable the self-provisioning](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/applications/projects/configuring-project-creation.html#disabling-project-self-provisioning_configuring-project-creation) for normal users and then have an external service (e.g. a Jenkins pipeline, a web service, ...) available for normal users that creates the namespace and populates the default pull secret.

Comment: It's not about new projects. It's about the existing project. Strimzi creates a new kafka cluster and creates a new service account for it, which has no pull secret linked and is therefore not able to pull the image.

Answer (score -2):

More often you would do this for each pod rather than each service account, but the answer is the same either way: write a mutating admission webhook. Or use an existing one that does the same thing, for example https://github.com/jainishshah17/tugger

Comment: Our cluster can only access images from that single Artifactory. Adding a pull secret to each and every pod is possible, but I would prefer to configure that on a cluster level. I would really avoid adding a custom webhook, when Openshift has that feature already built in.